# i want to use Oracle Apex Dynamic Action to redirect me to another page in my application AFTER form validation is passed and the form is submitted

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

i have an Interactive form with the following fields:

P5_APPLICANTFK 
P5_ANIMALFK 
P5_DATEOFAPPLICATION 
P5_REASONOFAPPLICATION 
P5_APPLICATIONAPPROVED

Constraints/validation that needs to be satisfied:

```
ALTER TABLE FOSTERAPPLICATION
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_duplicate UNIQUE (ANIMALFK, APPLICATIONAPPROVED);
```

After the form has been filled out without any errors (unique constraint above) I would like to use a dynamic action to redirect me to another page in the same application.

Answer (score 2):

Why dynamic action? Use a **branch**, it is designed for that purpose.

Locate it on the "Processing" tab; right-click "Processing" and select "Create branch" from the menu.

Comment: i tried to use a branch but the problem is that my validation does not work when i use the branch. e.g. if my form is incorrectly filled out and i submit it, i am redirected to a different page anyway.

Comment: How come? If validation fails, it stops execution so - how can you submit the page and be redirected elsewhere?

Comment: you were right. I figured out a way using a branch the problem now is that for example: i have created a branch to execute 'after processing' but it is not redirecting after passing validation and submitting the form.